# How to make YouTube video with screen projection in background?

Tags: video-editor, youtube, greenscreen, studio

I want to know, how we can create YouTube videos like this channel:

In here we can notice that the Daniel Shiffman's laptop screen is projected in the background, but it doesn't look like a Projector projecting on the wall behind him.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this on a live webcast with only a laptop. You will want either:

1. a dedicated PC with an I7 or better CPU, appropriate video hardware (Blackmagic capture card or comparable) and software switch (Wirecast or comparable), or
2. a hardware video switch (Blackmagic ATEM 1 M/E or comparable).

Having purchased both types of systems in the past few years, the two options come out to about the same price, and I'm partial to the hardware solution.

Once you have the hardware and software in place, you can greenscreen the entire room, which creates lighting issues, or only a section behind the lecturer and use picture-in-picture to minimize the amount of space that the green-screen requires (and the lighting problems that go with it).

After that, the output of the laptop is just an input to the capture card or ATEM switch.

Comment: I am inclined toward using Laptop based solution and not separate Hardware. Is there a free software that can give me the desired output? Also, can you link some detailed video or blog tutorial to set this up?

Comment: Short answer,  not on a live webcast. Live video takes lots of dedicated processing power.

Comment: I agree. But my question is not for live webcast. Can you tell me about free software and also any detailed tutorial link or youtube video to follow to achieve this?

Comment: In post production any mid level or better video editing software will do this. Premiere pro is inexpensive to lease through creative cloud, a months rental being comparable to a single nice meal at a restaurant. Im not familiar with the free alternatives to make a recommendation.  This tutorial should get you started with the technique. .. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=uwnlASSHaEY

Answer (score 0):

It's a green screen, otherwise known as chroma keying.  Blue is also used, especially for blonde subjects, or people in green clothing/ costume.  It's not being projected behind him.  If you were standing in the room, you'd just see a green wall.  But it is possible to key footage live, and even to stream a live chroma key.  You just need the right hardware and/ or software.

Comment: Any link to the details of how to create this magic at home will be highly appreciated. I am looking at some sort of DIY video link where I can stream a live from my own laptop which is also in the same video, just like this Youtube link i shared in this question?

Comment: If you want to stream live, Wirecast provides luma and chroma keying options. My studio used Wirecast for many years before upgrading to a Black Magic ATEM 1 M/E, at roughly the same total cost as a PC and hardware capable of handling Wirecast.

Comment: If you're happy doing this in post production, Adobe Premier pro, Sony Vegas Pro, and other mid- to pro-grade software all support luma and chroma keying. Google "youtube chroma key demo" to get about 668,000 results

Comment: https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/ultimatte

Comment: @JasonConrad cool device (I want!), but a little pricier than the average home user can manage